# Activerecord-import upsert with non unique columns into postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord-import

I am trying to use activerecord-import to import data and I ran into an issue. In case the row already exists it needs to be updated else it needs to be created. The unique rows in the table are defined by a combination of two columns where each column value might not be unique in the table. How would I go about using the on_duplicate_key_update's conflict_target since the columns are not unique columns.

Now for the details. I have a model called Order, below is a simplified version of the columns in the Order model.

```
id
order_number
sku_number
quantity
```

The unique rows in the database are identified by a combination of order_number and sku_number. The id column is auto incremented. Normally I could do something like the following if I have an unique column as an identifier. So in the example below I would use the id column as the conflict_target assuming the id column was the unique identifier.

```
order = Order.create(order_number: '1', sku_number: '1', quantity: 100)
order.quantity = 200
Order.import [order], on_duplicate_key_update: {conflict_target: [:id], columns: [:quantity]}
```

and that would update the quantity because the order already exists.

But what I need is something like

```
Order.import [order], on_duplicate_key_update: {conflict_target: [:order_number, :sku_number], columns: [:quantity]}
```

Where the order_number and the sku_number would uniquely identify the conflict row.

But that fails since Postgres is expecting an unique column for the conflict_target.

Is there some way to call on_duplicate_key_update with non unique columns i.e. order_number and sku_number?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. I am putting down the solution in case someone else runs into the same problem.

I ended up creating a unique index on Order

```
class AddUniqueKeyConstraintToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :orders, [:order_number, :sku_number], unique: true
  end
end
```

activerecord-import supports using an index as the constraint. So I ended up doing something like

```
order = Order.last
order.quantity = 200
Order.import [order], on_duplicate_key_update: {conflict_target: [:order_number, :sku_number], index_name: :index_orders_on_order_number_and_sku_number, columns: [:quantity]}
```

Where index_orders_on_order_number_and_sku_number is the name of the index created by the migration. Which updated the quantity from the previous value to 200 without creating an additional record.

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do the same is to create an CONSTRAIANT as unique combination of multiple columns. In the migration file after the create_table we can:

```
create_table :board_statistics do |t|
    t.string :hostname, null: false
    t.string :slot
    …

end
```

Create just an unique index

`add_index :board_statistics, [:hostname, :slot, :serial_number], unique: true`

or create an constraint

```
execute <<-SQL                                                                                                        
       ALTER TABLE board_statistics  
        ADD CONSTRAINT one_card_xan_slot UNIQUE (hostname, slot, serial_number);
 SQL
```

Constraint can be used in Activerecord-import gem like:

```
BoardStatistic.import columns, on_duplicate_key_ignore: {constraint_name: :one_card_xan_slot}
```